no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications]and contenttype [text/html]
I am trying to deploy my application to AWS Fargate. I'm using Spring Boot version 3.1.2, JDK 17, Spring cloud 2022.0.2, spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server 4.0.1 version.
Eureka runs and UI is working fine. When I try to run my service it is giving me this error due to which it is not working. How can I fix it?
1734336732524,[DEBUG] 2024-12-16 13:42:12.524 [/] [main] SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute 67 [] [] - Ending a session and starting anew
1734336732584,[DEBUG] 2024-12-16 13:42:12.584 [/] [main] CompositeLog.debug 127 [] [] - HTTP GET http://abcd.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8761/ServiceDiscovery/eureka/apps/
1734336732711,"[DEBUG] 2024-12-16 13:42:12.711 [/] [main] CompositeLog.debug 127 [] [] - Accept=[application/json, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-jackson-smile, application/cbor, application/*+json, application/*+xml]"
1734336732819,[DEBUG] 2024-12-16 13:42:12.819 [/] [main] CompositeLog.debug 127 [] [] - Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
1734336732825,"[INFO ] 2024-12-16 13:42:12.825 [/] [main] RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute 84 [] [] - Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://abcd.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8761/ServiceDiscovery/eureka/}, exception=Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications] and content type [text/html] stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications] and content type [text/html]"
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:124)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1132)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1115)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:865)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:145)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:135)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1045)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:958)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:396)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:247)
1734336732825,  at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:242)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:68)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:320)
1734336732825,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
1734336732825,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
1734336732825,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
1734336732825,  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:365)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:362)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:128)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:116)
1734336732825,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
1734336732825,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
1734336732825,  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
1734336732825,  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:482)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getEurekaClient(<generated>)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179)
1734336732825,  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357)
1734336732825,  at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)



Hints in the exception "can't find for content type [text/html]". There is also :8761/ServiceDiscovery/eureka/ which isn't the standard path for the eureka server.

context path of my servicediscovery is /ServiceDiscovery.. That is why I have added that to URL.
